# Why Python extract data so fast from Excel when changing input information

Tags: python

I use Excel to download data from capitaliq. So basically, I put firm_id(ticker) in a cell, say A1 and data will be pull into cells A2:A10 as I already put formula there.

Here what I see. If I manually enter firm_id in Excel, it takes few second for Excel to get data.

However, when I use python to loop through a number of firm_id and extract data for each id, the whole list is done almost instantly. I do not see firm_id changed nor data pulled out in the Excel file itself!

I go back and manually check and the data is extracted correctly.

I am curious what make the difference between manually entering firm_id (and of course wait for the data to shown up) vs. what Python does. Does Python capture the data somewhere in Excel before it brought into display? HHC

```
Cell_range = ws.Range("A1")

tickers_list=["BAC","C","A","F","zoooo","TSLA","D"]
full_file=[]
for ticker in tickers_list:
    Cell_range.Value = ticker #put ticker in taget cell

    # Using Client to download the open data
    xlApp = client.GetObject(None, "Excel.Application")
    books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
    ws = books.Worksheets('Sheet1')
    ws.Visible = 1

    #returns tuple, then list
    shift_1 = ws.Range("A2:A10").Value
    l=list(shift_1)

    full_file.append(l)
full_file
```

Comment: Sounds clear to me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Python blats the data into the cells quicker than you can, and possibily before doing any external calls, when you enter, it calls, block and populates where as python populates all the cells before the call. This is just an assumption but seems logical to me.